App ID: 2217803681890448. Register app in production problem
I'm trying to implement authorization to the application via a Facebook account, everything works fine in the local application and I can log in, after switching to production mode I have a problem with logging in, the error is as follows: "Login via Facebook is currently unavailable for this application because it is in progress. updating with additional details. Please try again later."
I also have a problem accessing public_profile resources. and I have a problem with creating Business Manager. Can You help me?
App ID: 2217803681890448
I tried to create a business manager account and get the public_profile resource verified, but it ends with errors. Please let me know if I am missing any configuration in the account, and if so, which one. Please also let me know if everything is OK with my account
